# Sort order doesn't persist between application restarts

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, stack-overflow-app

I like to see my questions sorted by newest.

However, whatever I last chose isn't remembered when I get out and reopen the app - it always goes back to sort by active.

The app should remember the last sort order and use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for spotting this! It's fixed as of version 1.0.1. We now persist both your sort order preference, and your search sort order preference.

Comment: I'm not getting a default sort order at all - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359267/why-is-there-no-active-sort-order-for-answers-indicated-on-my-account