# Why is there no active sort-order for answers indicated on my account?

Tags: bug

Note that there is no default sorting selected for answers on my account:

[image: No default sorting indication]

But if I open the same URL in an incognito window I see the following

[image: With default sorting indication]

Note: This behaviour is not seen in a brand new account (which defaults to "Votes").

Comment: I wonder if there is a hidden setting which sets your selected sort setting, which isn't initialized for your account (because you never used it before?). If you change the sorting, then it works for the whole page, but I can't find a something for that in the user account settings.

Comment: I am reluctant to test setting it, in case I destroy account state that could be useful for tracking down an elusive bug.

Comment: Creating a new account to test it out would be trivial, though.

Comment: @yivi - Good idea. I just tested, and it is correct in new accounts.

Comment: @yivi I guess a new account would behave the same as an anonymous user: it get's a default value. Peters account is quite old, so it can be the case the existing accounts didn't got migrated correctly for a new sort setting and therefore didn't got a default value.